# Magento 2.3.0: Magento Unprotected XML

Tags: magento2.3, vulnerability

I'm getting the following vulnerability issue when using the Magento Security Scan:

> We have determined that your Magento installation's configuration file(s) are publicly accessible over HTTP.

'**.user.ini**'

I see the `.user.ini` file in the root of my Magento install, but not sure what it's for or how to pass the vulnerability scan.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions for `.user.ini` can be `-rw-r-----` (or 640 in octal). This removes access for anyone other than owner and group members. (As Hunter said, you can check permissions by running ls -la in your Linux terminal/shell).

Our Magento 2.3 site is running with `.user.ini` permissions of 640, so I can verify they do work. I ran the security scan today and our permissions on `.user.ini` pass. (However, I notice that I also got a [false positive](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297484/magento-security-scan-erroneous-results-falses-positive) for another issue so the scanner tool is not perfect.)

Regarding file and group ownership, our httpd service (Apache) runs as user and group `apache`. We give user `apache` read only access to `.user.ini` and we have a dedicated group named `webdev` (for developers) that has rw access to that file and is a member of `wheel`. `apache` is not a member of `webdev` and does not have sudo permission.

You can change owner and group in the Linux shell like this:

```
chown apache:webdev .user.ini
```

The command to create a group is `groupadd` on CentOS. See https://blacksaildivision.com/centos-create-user-group for more details.

Substitute your own user and group. It's best if the httpd service (apache) does not have write permissions on files in the DocumentRoot (pub/).

Answer (score 2):

> PRODSECBUG-1883: Leakage of Custom PHP settings from .user.ini File
>
> Description:
> Access to certain private files is not protected.

You can find more information about this and other bugs [here](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.2.7-and-2.1.16-security-update).

This issue was addressed in 2.3.0. Make sure your permissions for .user.ini are set correctly. You may find [this](https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001868933-How-to-set-Magento-2-permissions-and-avoid-installation-errors) article helpful.

Permissions for .user.ini should be `-rw-r--r--`. Check by running `ls -la` in your linux console.

Comment: Thanks, I checked permissions and it shows as `-rw-r--r--` for the **.user.ini** file. Also trying to find where I can apply that patch, doesn't seem to be a download on the magento page.

Comment: Is the file owned by the correct user? I'm not sure if the contents of the file matter, but you can refer to the original .user.ini [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/.user.ini)

Comment: Thanks @Hunter, yeah I've checked permissions and everything should be good to go in those terms, also the file contents are the same and haven't been edited.