# Magento Security Scan Erroneous Results (falses positive)?

Tags: magento2, security-scan-tool, vulnerability

The Magento Security Scan returned this vulnerability:

```
API ACL - Failed.
API ACL Patch not detected (APPSEC-1679)
Apply the Magento 2.0.14/2.1.7 Security Update immediately.
```

However, my site is running Magento 2.3.3 (released Oct 2019). The [patch mentioned](https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.0.14-and-2.1.7-security-update) is dated May 31, 2017 and is for a much older version.

> APPSEC-1679: APIs vulnerable to CSRF
>   Product(s) Affected:  Magento CE and EE prior to 2.0.14/2.1.7
>   Fixed In: Magento CE and EE 2.0.14/2.1.7

Are other people seeing this error (false positive) with Magento 2.3.3 and the Magento Security Scan tool?

Is there anything else I should know about this particular reported issue with my site?

Comment: Do you require 2FA for all admin users?

Comment: @Hunter - we are working on that as well as OAuth-based authentication.

Comment: Try making 2FA mandatory for every admin account and trying again after

Answer (score 0):

From Magento support I got the following answer,

> Please make sure that Configuration->Services->Magento Web API->Web API Security->Allow Anonymous Guest Access is set to "Off". It is probably turned on. Thank you!